# GTK2 and Perl Manual

Tags: perl, manual, gtk2

I am learning Perl for the first time, but I am finding it difficult to find some well documented documentation regarding the language with the GTK2 Library. I am fully aware of the [Perl Manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/), but it doesn't cover anything on GTK2. So, where can I find a well documented Perl with GTK2 Manual? As documented as PHP for example.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Perl GTK2 home](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/)? They have some [documentation](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/) there.

By the way, there's a command called `perldoc` that will display the built in documentation of any Perl module. It also has the complete documentation for any function, pragmas, etc. For example:

```
$ perldoc Gtk2          #Help on the Gtk2 module
$ perldoc Data::Dumper  #Help with the Data::Dumper Perl module
$ perldoc -f open       #Help with the built in Perl _open_ command
$ perldoc -q data       #Questions in the FAQ that have the keyword _data_ in them.
```

Of course, the [Perldoc webpage](http://perldoc.perl.org) has all of the standard included documentation in it. CPAN modules will display their Perl documentation on the CPAN webpage with that module.

By the way, you know about the `cpan` command? This is how you [download and install](http://www.perlhowto.com/installing_cpan_modules) a module you find in the [CPAN webpage](http://search.cpan.org). All this stuff is nice, but there's a lot of assumption that most people know about this stuff. I was a Perl programmer for over a decade before I realized you were suppose to use the `cpan` command to install Perl modules. I didn't know about the `perldoc` command until a few years ago although I already knew about POD (plain old documentation) which is Perl's standard way of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The best documentation I have found is the Gtk2-Perl Study guide by Dirk van der Walt
which is linked from here.

http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/

There is a really good example by grant mclean here at
http://live.gnome.org/GTK2-Perl/GladeXML/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for third party modules is (in theory at least) included with the module itself and is accessible via [`perldoc Module::Name`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) and various [web interfaces to CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/Gtk2).

Answer (score 0):

The [GladeXML tutorial on GNOME Live](http://live.gnome.org/GTK2-Perl/GladeXML/Tutorial) may be useful, it uses Glade but is a good start for Gtk2+Perl.